# How to convert array of connections between graph nodes into a 2D array of nodes with their connections?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, graph

Let's have an undirected graph given by vertices which are represented by adjacent nodes:

`(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1), (2, 5), (4, 5)` which looks like this:

[image: Example of an undirected graph]

The order is completely random and every connection is there only once, so if there's already `(1, 2)`, there won't be `(2, 1)`. I have an array `int vertices[12] = {1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5}`. I would like to create an array where `i-th` index represents a node number `i` and the corresponding sub-array represents its neighbors, so in this case like this: `int graph[5][4] = {{2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}}.` I tried going through it by first looking at all the even nodes and than the odd nodes but I kept running into a problem with two same nodes. Maybe I could first order it somehow before I start assigning. What's the simplest way?

Comment: `I tried going through it by first looking at all the even nodes and than the odd nodes` seems strange because your vertices are given in any order. Having N elements in *vertices* you need in the worst case an array `[(N+1)/2][(N+1)/2]` (allowing to end each list of vertices connected to one with a special value, or to place the number of these nodes at the index 0 or `(N+1)/2-1`), then go throw *vertices* stepping by 2 and update the nodes lists for both `vertices[i]` and `vertices[i+1]`, then if you want sort each list

Comment: "What's the simplest way?" is broad and depends on various factors.  Perhaps post what you have tried and then ask for simplification with details of what aspect is important simplify.

Comment: "What's the simplest way?" A for-loop where you handle 2 values in each loop